# How to jump to an IP address when connected to a remote server on VS Code?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-server

I've never connected to a remote server before. I want to connect to my company's remote server then jump to another IP address.

I followed VS Code Guide [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_forwarding-a-port-creating-ssh-tunnel) and connected to the server, but I'm not sure how to jump to the IP address.

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out.

I wanted to connect to my company's private server. In order to do that, I must connect to my company's host server. When I'm in the host server, I have to connect to a private server (sorry for not phrasing my question in a clearer sense).

I'm leaving my solution here for future reference.
In VS Code, do F1 (fn+F1 on Mac) -> Remote-SSH: Connect to Host -> Configure SSH Host -> /Users//.ssh/config.

From there, edit the config file as follows:

```
Host <host-name>
  HostName <IP-address>
  Port <specify-port-number-here>
  User <user-name>

### The Remote Host
Host <private-server-name>
  HostName <IP-address>
  Port <specify-port-number-here>
  User <user-name>
  ProxyJump <host-name>
```

Save the config file and connect to the private server by F1 -> Remote-SSH: Connect to Host -> private-server-name

Comment: this is not working for me. Infact, answer above this working. Can you describe how you marked this a working solution?

Comment: After trying numerous configs, `ProxyJump` finally did the trick for me. Using VSCodium on Linux and the [Open Remote - SSH](https://open-vsx.org/extension/jeanp413/open-remote-ssh) extension. Cheers!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you, I tried a lot of things to do host-jumping ssh, only this one made it work.

Answer (score 7):

I've managed to get it working using the ProxyCommand option, as described in the [VSCode Remote SSH Tips & Tricks page](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks#_proxycommand), as chocolatte's answer didn't work for me with VSCode 1.51.1:

```
# Jump box with public IP address
Host jump-box
    HostName <Jump-Box-IP>
    User <Your-Jump-Box-User-Name>
    IdentityFile path/to/.ssh/id_rsa

# Target machine with private IP address
Host target-box
    HostName <IP address of target>
    User <Your-Private-Machine's-User-Name>
    IdentityFile path/to/.ssh/id_rsa
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jump-box
```

Note: you can use the same IdentityFile for both hosts

Update: After a while this stopped working. What solved this issue is changing ssh to ssh.exe:

```
ProxyCommand ssh.exe -q -W %h:%p jump-box
```